# multiple Ajax with same jsonpCallback as done callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have different Ajax calls to same API with *different path and query* in URL, but with with *same jsonpCallback I can't change*

When I called one Ajax url - everything fine!

But when I need get responses from multiple, I got errors, cause their executing at once. I tryed callbacks, I tryed "async:false", I tryed "returning ajax with when,then,done etc - NOTHING WORKS as I expected :(

```
function timenow() {
  var a = new Date,
    b = a.getMinutes();
  b < 10 && (b = "0" + b);
  var c = a.getHours();
  c > 12 && (c -= 12);
  var d = c + ":" + b;
  return d
}

function ajaxCall(p, callback) {
  if (p == 1) {
    url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-93100300&offset=0&count=1&filter=owner&callback=logResults'
  } else {
    url = "https://api.github.com/users/jeresig?callback=logResults"
  }
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: false,
    jsonpCallback: "logResults",
    cache: true,
  }).done(function(r) {
    callback(r);
  });
}

$.when(
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r);
    console.log(r.data.avatar_url + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r);
    console.log(r.response[1].id + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.bio + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].id + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.blog + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].from_id + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.company + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].to_id + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.created_at + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].date + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.email + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].post_type + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.events_url + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].text + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.followers + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].is_pinned + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.followers_url + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].reposts.count + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.following + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].likes.count + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.following_url + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].comments.count + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.gists_url + ' ' + timenow());
  })
).done(console.log('Ajaxing done ' + timenow()));
```

[image: LOG ERROR]

I think problem in same jsonpCallback, so when I use callback in ajax it always rewrites it with new function, so I am getting errors.

P.S. Still can't set up async to false, working sample https://jsfiddle.net/ypmkn5k0/

```
<div id="log"></div>

<script>
$.ajaxSetup({ async: false});


$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.github.com/users/jeresig?callback=logResults',
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonp: false,
  jsonpCallback: "logResults",
  cache: true,
  async: false,
}).done(function(r) {
  $('#log').append(r.data.avatar_url+'</br>');
});

$('#log').append('Ajaxing done </br>');
</script>
```

P.S.S Oh, I checked documentation once again, now I understand, very sad(((

> Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support
>   synchronous operation.

P.S.S.S I did last try with callbacking and it's WORKS, FUK-FUK-FUK, DON'T KNOW WHY IT WASn'T ON REAL PROJECT, BUT I WILL TRY TO EMPLIMENT IT:

```
function timenow(){var a=new Date,b=a.getMinutes();b<10&&(b="0"+b);var c=a.getHours();c>12&&(c-=12);var d=c+":"+b;return d}

        function ajaxCall(p,callback) {
        if(p==1){ 
        url='https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-93100300&offset=0&count=1&filter=owner&callback=logResults' 
        } else {
        url="https://api.github.com/users/jeresig?callback=logResults" 
        }
        $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: false, 
        jsonpCallback: "logResults",
        cache: true,
        success: function (r) {
        callback(r);
        },
        });
        }


        ajaxCall(0,function(r){console.log(r); console.log(r.data.avatar_url+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(1,function(r){console.log(r); console.log(r.response[1].id+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(0,function(r){console.log(r.data.bio+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(1,function(r){console.log(r.response[1].id+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(0,function(r){console.log(r.data.blog+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(1,function(r){console.log(r.response[1].from_id+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(0,function(r){console.log(r.data.company+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(1,function(r){console.log(r.response[1].to_id+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(0,function(r){console.log(r.data.created_at+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(1,function(r){console.log(r.response[1].date+' '+timenow());   
        ajaxCall(0,function(r){console.log(r.data.email+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(1,function(r){console.log(r.response[1].post_type+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(0,function(r){console.log(r.data.events_url+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(1,function(r){console.log(r.response[1].text+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(0,function(r){console.log(r.data.followers+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(1,function(r){console.log(r.response[1].is_pinned+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(0,function(r){console.log(r.data.followers_url+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(1,function(r){console.log(r.response[1].reposts.count+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(0,function(r){console.log(r.data.following+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(1,function(r){console.log(r.response[1].likes.count+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(0,function(r){console.log(r.data.following_url+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(1,function(r){console.log(r.response[1].comments.count+' '+timenow());
        ajaxCall(0,function(r){console.log(r.data.gists_url+' '+timenow());
            console.log('Ajaxing done '+timenow());
        });
        });
        });
        });
        });
        });
        });
        });
        });
        });
        });
        });
        });
        });
        });
        });
        });
        });
        }); 
        });             
        });
        });
        });
```

[image]

Comment: They can't be executing at once, because Javascript is single-threaded.

Comment: Where is the definition of `logResults`?

Comment: Can you please include the error information you are getting? The whole point of AJAX is the asynchronicity, and you can ignore the comment above because once an ajax communication is started the rest of the function will continue.

Comment: I understand it's asynchronicity, the only solution I see by now is Using Backend Proxy with Random Jquery Callback by defult :(((((

Comment: You have two invariant, hard-coded URLs, therefore hit two servers hard with exactly the same two requests over and over, machine-gun style. Why not make just *one request per sever* then log out the various response properties *en bloc*? Fix that, *then* worry about why it's not working;

Comment: Cause one request per server works - fine, but I need chain, this is just example, in real I call one server with different API methods one-by-one - and getting same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I see is in your .done() at the very end. This should be enclosed in a function. That and I think it would be better if you declared your 'url' variable so that there is no confusion over it's localization.

```
function timenow() {
  var a = new Date,
    b = a.getMinutes();
  b < 10 && (b = "0" + b);
  var c = a.getHours();
  c > 12 && (c -= 12);
  var d = c + ":" + b;
  return d
}

function ajaxCall(p, callback) {
  var url = 'https://api.github.com/users/jeresig?callback=logResults';
  if (p == 1) {
    url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-93100300&offset=0&count=1&filter=owner&callback=logResults'
  }
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: false,
    jsonpCallback: "logResults",
    cache: true,
  }).done(function(r) {
    callback(r);
  });
}

$.when(
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r);
    console.log(r.data.avatar_url + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r);
    console.log(r.response[1].id + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.bio + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].id + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.blog + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].from_id + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.company + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].to_id + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.created_at + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].date + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.email + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].post_type + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.events_url + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].text + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.followers + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].is_pinned + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.followers_url + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].reposts.count + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.following + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].likes.count + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.following_url + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(1, function(r) {
    console.log(r.response[1].comments.count + ' ' + timenow());
  }),
  ajaxCall(0, function(r) {
    console.log(r.data.gists_url + ' ' + timenow());
  })
).done(function() { console.log('Ajaxing done ' + timenow()); });
```

If you are going to use the async: false argument, then there's no point in enclosing all of these in a .when/.done, and if you know that you can't call these asynchronously, then I would recommend that you remove the .when logic and simply call the function sequentially with the async: false property.

It would also be helpful to see your jsonpCallback. If you have any variables or resources that would be considered shared, then that could also be a problem.

Comment: you were right about func inside .done, but how to set it up async to false? still asynchronicity https://jsfiddle.net/ypmkn5k0/ :(

Comment: You can use an approach similar to recursion if async is giving you issues. Have a look at this and let me know if you have any questions. https://jsfiddle.net/ypmkn5k0/2/

Comment: I don't know your end game, but here's something to consider in terms of a cleaner, more easy-to-read approach. https://jsfiddle.net/ypmkn5k0/3/

Comment: end of the goal - just catch some data from URLs chain without backending proxy - your examples were right too, but I prefer now create object with functions&callbacks: like `API = { method1:function(callback){}, method2:function(callback){} }`